# Recommended way to display an error message without resorting to @ModelAttribute with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have the following **method skeleton** in a **Spring MVC application**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/activateMember/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
public String activateMember(@PathVariable("token") String token) {
...
}
```

I am trying to display an error message if the `token` is invalid for some reason. However I have no `ModelAttribute` in the method arguments and I don't really want one. But of course I can't use an `Errors` or `BindingResults` argument because of the absence of a `ModelAttribute` and its corresponding `form`.

So my question is:
**what is the recommended way to display an error message given the above method signature** and without introducing a ModelAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `String` you've returned from the method is a viewname (Spring default) then simply create a view for this case and do like:

```
@RequestMapping()
public String activateMember(@PathVariable("token") String token) {
    if(checkToken(token)){
        doProcess();
        return "userprofile";
    } else {
        return "badtoken"
    }
}
```

In more complicated case you may have a hierarchy of exceptions, related to bad tokens. (Token is expired, token is just incorrect and so on). You can register an [`@ExceptionHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) in the same controller:

```
@RequestMapping()
public String activateMember(@PathVariable("token") String token) {
    return activate(token); // This method may throw TokenException and subclasses.
}

@ExceptionHandler(TokenException.class)
public ModelAndView tokenException(TokenException e){
    // some code
    return new ModelAndView("badtoken", "exception", e);
}
```